# Can I tell within application code, on what outermost port of my server the app is accessed?

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to open with the question that I really want answered. I want the URL at which outside users can access a particular part of my application.

In my server's setup, we're using Nginx as a reverse proxy, so my app is confugured to be at port 9000. But I can't point users at this, because they can't access that port. Users can access port 8080. But this is part of my system configuration and could (I think) change. Also it does change from development to staging to production. So, I would like to avoid hard-coding this if possible.

So then my question, can I somehow, dynamically, tell the "outermost" port that an incoming request is received at? Possibly through passing a header down from Nginx? I'm thinking of X-Forwarded-For, except I want to know what URL the client contacted to reach me (the server), not what IP address the client is contacting the server from. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$server_port](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_port) variable holds the port the client connected to.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I think I will switch to using this. I just hardcoded the port I was using as a header inside my nginx config on prod. I figured I would see this when/if I change my system's setup. As long as it's not in the code--where I won't see it. In development, it didn't matter.